# Normal distribution: how to get probability under a certain sigma value symmetrically?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, normal-distribution

For Gaussian/normal distribution we know that 1 sigma (standard deviation) around the mode/mean/median encloses almost 68.2% probability; 2 sigma -> 95.4% probability. Is there a function in python that spits out the probability that is enclosed between any given {-x,x} interval? More importantly, I also need the inverse of that function. The inverse function gives me the value of x for which a given probability is enclosed within {-x,x}.

I searched `scipy.stats` but could not find my answer. `scipy.stats.norm.cdf` is the closest one, and I can get the function as: `cdf(x)-cdf(-x)` and construct the inverse function as:

```
import scipy.stats as st
def fun(x):
    return st.norm.cdf(x)-st.norm.cdf(-x)
def inv_fun(p):
    p=p+(1.0-p)/2.
    return st.norm.ppf(p)
```

But I wanted to check if there is already such a function written in `scipy` or somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.:
I know I will attract some negative points here. Please believe me, the probability under {-x,x} is important in many fields.

Comment: The function does not exist elsewhere in the `stats` library; it expected to use to the quantile function `.ppf`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. At least, I can come back to this thread whenever I need these functions in the future.